# Javascript conversion/ETL library?

Tags: javascript, etl, data-formats

I'm considering creating a new Open Source library in Javascript to handle common data format conversions, but I would love to avoid re-inventing the wheel if possible. Is there an existing library that has the following features?

- **Modular loaders** to read input from different data formats (e.g. XML, CSV, JSON, SQL dump, fixed-width text, potentially some binary formats, custom formats, etc)
- Data loaded into a **Javascript data structure** and optional custom transform functions applied
- **Modular exporters/emitters** to output to different data formats (as above)

I know various libraries that can handle some of these data types, but usually in specific circumstances or combinations, and without the modular input/output structure I'm imagining.

Does a Javascript data format conversion library currently exist?

Comment: Did it ever happened? Is this library available now?

Comment: Got no answers, never had the opportunity to build the library :(. Sorry.